# How to expand a data frame by filling range of value using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(patient = c("k2-01-003", "k2-01-008"), y_start = c(0.292, 
      0.048), visit_str = c("9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17"
      ), nof_visits = 10:9), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
      "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It looks like this:

```
> df 
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  patient   y_start visit_str                    nof_visits
  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>                             <int>
1 k2-01-003   0.292 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18         10
2 k2-01-008   0.048 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17             9
```

What I want to do is to expand the `y_start` value for every patient along the `visit_str`
the expansion is to be increment by 0.01. The desired result looks like this:

```
  patient             y_new   visit_str                  
  k2-01-003            0.292      9,
  k2-01-003            0.302      10,
  k2-01-003            0.312      11,
  k2-01-003            0.322      12,
  k2-01-003            0.332      13,
  k2-01-003            0.342      14,
  k2-01-003            0.352      15,
  k2-01-003            0.362      16,
  k2-01-003            0.372      17,
  k2-01-003            0.382      18         
     ..... etc ....
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way :

Split the data on comma to get all visits in  different rows and fir each patient add an increment of 0.01 to each `y_start` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(visit_str, sep = ',') %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  mutate(y_start = y_start + seq(0, by = 0.01, length.out = n()))

#  patient   y_start visit_str nof_visits
#   <chr>       <dbl> <chr>          <int>
# 1 k2-01-003   0.292 9                 10
# 2 k2-01-003   0.302 10                10
# 3 k2-01-003   0.312 11                10
# 4 k2-01-003   0.322 12                10
# 5 k2-01-003   0.332 13                10
# 6 k2-01-003   0.342 14                10
# 7 k2-01-003   0.352 15                10
# 8 k2-01-003   0.362 16                10
# 9 k2-01-003   0.372 17                10
#10 k2-01-003   0.382 18                10
#11 k2-01-008   0.048 9                  9
#12 k2-01-008   0.058 10                 9
#13 k2-01-008   0.068 11                 9
#14 k2-01-008   0.078 12                 9
#15 k2-01-008   0.088 13                 9
#16 k2-01-008   0.098 14                 9
#17 k2-01-008   0.108 15                 9
#18 k2-01-008   0.118 16                 9
#19 k2-01-008   0.128 17                 9
```